# Is it possible to achieve a title in online games?

Tags: online-chess, titles

I am a relatively weak player (~1600 chess.com) who mostly plays online blitz. Recently I've been thinking about shooting for a title (e.g. USCF expert) as a long-term goal. The area where I live has always had a relatively few OTB matches, and is even worse with the COVID pandemic.

Is there any title which can be achieve partially or completely via online play? Of course, I could always shoot for a particular rating, but a title somehow feels more significant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any title it's possible to achieve partially or completely via online play?

Yes, there are. FIDE has their own [online platform](https://chessarena.com/) and offer [FIDE titles](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B11FOATitlesForLowerRatingBand) for achievements on their online Arena.

> 1.1  FIDE introduces and recognises titles designated for the chess players of the lower rating band. Ordered hierarchically from higher to lower status, these titles are:
> 1.1.1   Arena Grandmaster (AGM or ag)
> 1.1.2   Arena International master (AIM or ai)
> 1.1.3   Arena FIDE master (AFM or af)
> 1.1.4   Arena Candidate master (ACM or ac)

These titles are available for rapid, blitz and bullet. To achieve a title at a particular level and time control you have to play 50 games of rapid, 100 games of blitz or 150 games of bullet. You also have to reach a particular rating for each title.

The rating requirements are:
AGM = 2000
AIM = 1700
AFM = 1400
ACM = 1100